# Character encoding conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string which contains Swedish characters and want to convert it to basic English.

```
name = "LänödmåtnÖng ÅjädårbÄn"
```

These characters should be converted as follows:

- `Å` use `A`
- `å` use `a`
- `Ä` use `A`
- `ä` use `a`
- `Ö` use `O`
- `ö` use `o`

Is there a simple way to do it? If I try:

```
ascii_to_string = name.unpack("U*").map{|s|s.chr}.join
```

It returns `L\xE4n\xF6dm\xE5tn\xD6ng \xC5j\xE4d\xE5rb\xC4n` as ASCII, but I want to convert it to English.

Comment: This won't convert the string from Swedish to English, it will only convert it from using Swedish characters to ASCII characters. Converting the word requires changing the spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/n,'').downcase.to_s
```

As found in [this post.](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1055-strip-accents-from-utf8-strings-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3):

Using OP's conversion table as input for the `tr` method:

```
#encoding: utf-8
name = "LänödmåtnÖng ÅjädårbÄn" 
p name.tr("ÅåÄäÖö", "AaAaOo") #=> "LanodmatnOng AjadarbAn"
```

Answer (score 1):

You already got decent answer, however there is a way that is easier to remember (no magical regular expressions):

```
name.parameterize
```

It changes whitespaces to dashes, so you need to handle it somehow, for example by processing each word separately:

```
name.split.map { |s| s.parameterize }.join ' '
```